# How do you repeat this method in array.length?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, selection-sort

In this program, I want the user to type in 20 product names. from the main method. which will pass down to the method named searchProducts. But for some reason, it doesn't work. It only let me type in once, and then it prints out all 16 products.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] products= {"Pencil pouch", "pen", "Pencil sharpener", "High lighters", "Markers", "Erasers",
            "Binder", "Notebooks", "Index cards", "Folders", "Glue", "Ruler", "Scissors", "Calculator",
            "Calendar", "Backpack"};

    System.out.println("Unordered list");
    displayProducts(products);
    sortProducts(products, 16);
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Ordered list");
    displayProducts(products);
}

 private static int searchProducts(String[] products) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String x = sc.nextLine();

    System.out.println("Enter name of product: ");
    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].equals(x))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}


private static void sortProducts(String products[],int n) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
        int minindex = i;
        String minStr = products[i];

        for(int j = i + 1; j < n; j++) {
            if(products[j].compareTo(minStr) < 0)
            {
                minStr = products[j];
                minindex = j;
            }
        }

        if(minindex != i)
        {
            String temp = products[minindex];
            products[minindex] = products[i];
            products[i] = temp;
        }
    }
}

private static void displayProducts(String[] products) {

    for(int i = 0; i < products.length; i++){

        System.out.println(products[i] + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't see any reason to expect the program presented to read *any* input.  There is code at the beginning of `searchProducts()` to read a single line, but that method does not appear ever to be invoked, and I don't see any other code that would read any input..

Comment: Your code block in not clear, from where you call `searhProduct`?

Answer (score 1):

The way you pass array parameter is just good.

There are several ways to pass arrays as parameter:

```java
(/*Other params,*/ String[] param) // this way
(String[] param /*, Other params*/) // or

(/*Other params,*/ String param[]) // this way
(String param[] /*, Other params*/) // or

// special case
// only as unique or last param of the params 
// because with it you can enter several String params as individuals 
(/*Other params, */ String... param)


// arrays of arrays
(String[] param[])
(String[][] param)
(String param[][] )
```

This is your problem:

```java
sortProducts(products, 20);
...
private static void sortProducts(String products[],int n) {
```

You pass 20 although your array is 16 sized. So error.

Change this way to not depend on the size.

```java
     sortProducts(products);
     ....
     private static void sortProducts(String products[]) { // no size passed
        int n = products.length; // read the size from the array
```

**EDIT 1 -------------**

In the code below, the user to type in N products. Then the array is printed, sorted and printed.  (NOT TESTED)

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int N = 20;
    String[] products = new String[N];

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    for(int i=0; i < N; i++) {
       System.out.println("Enter name of product "+ (i+1) +" : ");
       String x = sc.nextLine();
       products[i] = x;
    }

    System.out.println("Unordered list");
    displayProducts(products);
    sortProducts(products);
    
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Ordered list");
    displayProducts(products);

    // search block
}
```

To search in the array, you can do something like that (NOT TESTED):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {

    // ... previous code



    // search block in main method
    System.out.println("Enter name of product to search, or \"stop\" to stop : ");
    String y = sc.nextLine();
    while(y != "stop") {
       int index = searchProducts(products, y);

       if( index == -1 )
           System.out.println("Product "+ y +" is not in array");
       else
           System.out.println("Product "+ y +" is at position "+ index);


       System.out.println("Enter name of product to search, or \"stop\" to stop : ");
       y = sc.nextLine();
    }
}

private static int searchProducts(String[] products, String p) {

    for (int i = 0; i < products.length; i++) {
        if (products[i].equals(p))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I fixed that problem, but it still doesn't let me ask 16 times. it only asks me once then as soon as I press enter, it prints out all of the products under the Unordered list and Ordered list.